# Mapping a URL to a single object (no collection), without id, via RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

According to the [URL conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_url-conventions), the REST adapter performs a `Find All` (`GET`) at the `plural` URL, and a `Find` (`GET`) to the `singular/id` URL. Now, one of my URLs does not follow this scheme, because the URL *itself* refers to a single object, *without* `id`.

The URL is: `api/me`. This will return data about the current logged-in user, but I am not able to map a route to it. This is my code:

```
App.Me = DS.Model.extend({
    full_name       : DS.attr('string'),
    email           : DS.attr('string'),
});

App.ProfileUserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Me.find();
    }
});
```

The RESTAdpater is generating this URL: `http://localhost:8000/api/mes`, which is not found on my server. How can I finetune the URL which is used for a given route?

Comment: Intuitivepixel's answer will help you call your 'me' API endpoint, but your server still needs some way to know which user is requesting their information. Is there any way you can pass the user's ID into your App.Me.find(<id>)?

Comment: The user is logged in, so the backend already knows what user we are talking about. It does not need any extra identification, since everything is in the session.

Comment: Besides, the ember frontend has no information about the user id, since the session is handled by another layer (the ember application is just a part of the frontend)

Comment: Ah right, fair enough.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your working syntax, sorry if if did not work right the way I showed ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What might help is to define `plurals` on your adapter. This could look like this:

```
App.Adapter.configure('plurals', { "me": "me" });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What worries me about this is that ember (ember-data?) is still thinking about the object here in plural terms (with a non-regular plural: "me" instead of "mes"). But actually I *know* that I am requesting a single object. I do not know what effects this will have in the selection of controller / model / view.

Comment: The only way I got this to work is: `App.Adapter.configure('plurals', { me: 'me' });`, as seen in the tests of `ember-data`. Setting the `plurals` hash directly had no effect (my `ember-data` version is `v0.13-30-ged99201`) Besides, the plural must be `me` (not `mes`). If you can adapt your answer, I accept it!

Comment: oh, I'm sorry for it did not work directly. I've edited my answer to reflect the change.